# Display image from my own xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I am designing an android application where am storing my images in my local xml file like

**imageview.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Source>
       <ID>001</ID>
       <Name>News</Name>
      <image>
          <title>News1</title>
          <location>file:http:server_ip/Images/news1.png</location>
        </image>
        <image>
          <title>News1</title>
          <location>http:server_ip/Images/bnews2.png</location>
        </image>   
      </Source>
```

Now i would like to display the image from this xml file into my `imageview` like-

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="here i would like to call my xml files image"/>
```

Edit:

I displayed this xml image with the help of [loadimage](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.in/2011/03/load-image-from-server-using-thread.html). Now my only question is how to display the image from the xml file and display the image.

Comment: @KailashDabhi can u give me some samples to understand it better as i referred many tutorials but still didn't got clear idea

Comment: hey actually @sankar ganesh is right

Comment: @AndroidOptimist **imageview.XML** is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am very wonder why your storing the image files such as news1.png and news2.png in your 'F' drive and how you except android to pack or bundle these inside the apk , 
you have two ways to do this

> Solution 1:
>
> 1. please store it in your drawable or in assets folder, how android can pack/bundle  this file with your apk.
>
> Solution 2:
>
> 1. If you still want to keep your files in 'f' drive,just imitate like downloading the files from server and placing to drawable or assets
>      depending upon your need, i mean keep your 'f' drive as a localhost,
>      without downloading or importing to drawable you cannot use that image
>      inside your app.

Comment: I already did that with drawable folder. Now i would like to store all my images in local folder and trying to call those images through xml file.

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: how you stored that images in drawable, can you please explain?

Comment: android:src="@drawable/button" and by calling this image view i can see my image

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: Then what's the need for your imageview.xml file ? and please what's the exact problem here your facing in your code?

Comment: I didn't face any problem.But that is my requirement. I need to store all my images in my database and instead of drawable i need to call all of them from my xml file

Comment: @Android Optimist: then please go through my step 2 in my answer.

Comment: I can't able to load my images from my own xml file ah?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: yes you cannot load images from your xml file, you should make it as localhost and write the file download code and use it in your application,something like you do imitate the server, ie., conside your machine is as a server, this what i have mentioned in my answer as solution 2

Comment: Thanks for ur ans. Can u pls give me an example of the same what u explained so that it will be easy.

Comment: @AndroidOptimist use web-services(JSON,XML,SOAP) to download the image from database.

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: you can have to create and run a webserver  in your machince and then downloading the file from that webserver ,http://127.0.0.1/news1.png , I have used PHP WAMP server , you can learn it from the youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE1NKRungXE

Comment: @SankarGanesh that link is not available. Thanks for ur guidance. Let me try

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: if this answer helps , please upvote and accept the answers, so that if anybody has a problem like this , they will try this solution, Thanks

Comment: @SankarGanesh sure let me try with your solution

Comment: @SankarGanesh here instead of my local drive is it possible to display images from my database folder(ie)in db, from images folder can i show all the images in their corresponding imageview?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist: please explain what is your database folder and where it is stored and it's location?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43728/discussion-between-androidoptimist-and-sankar-ganesh)

Comment: @SankarGanesh now i loaded my image on my server and from there i displayed my image in my imageview.Now i want to display image from my xml file which contains the path of the image.How to achieve this